# Retrieve carbon date from database

Tags: php, laravel

```
   $rankArray = [
        'ranks' => $product[0]['productSalesRank']->pluck('rank'),
        'dates' => $product[0]['productSalesRank']->pluck('created_at')
    ];


    $rankArray['dates']->transform(function ($item) {
        return $item->format('d-m-Y');
    });
```

Having to transform everytime I retrieve the created_at/updated_at date from the database seems so inefficient, is there a simplier way of doing this?

I want to keep the date as Carbon, but in some instances, do just want the "value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a getter in your productSalesRank's Model(?) that does all the work for readying your dates.

Model:

```
class ProductSalesRank extends Model
{
   protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at']; 
   // whatever other columns you want to use Carbon on ^.

   public function getCreatedAtHumanAttribute() {
       return $this->created_at->format('d-m-Y');
   }
}
```

View/Controller/Wherever:

```
$productSalesRank->created_at_human;  // will print it like you defined it in the model.
```

---

Why _human?

Sometimes later in the code you will find yourself needing the Carbon features on the created_at value. When you use format(), it returns a string, stripped out of Carbon features.

---

[Update]

Earlier we created a getter/accessor. As far as I know, you can't pass a variable like:

`->created_at_human('mm')` because it isn't a method, it is an accessor.

In your Model, create a function.

```
public function myFunction($format) {
   return $this->created_at->format($format);
}
```

In your view, simple:

```
$productSalesRank->myFunction('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: This is great, is it possible to do this -   public function getCreatedAtHumanAttribute($format) {
       return $this->created_at->format($format);
   }

Comment: No in that way but possible in another. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an accessor to your model, that automatically converts the data to the desired format. More about: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: This loses the Carbon ability, which I do not want to do.  I was hoping Laravel would just have a solution similar to

    dates' => $product[0]['productSalesRank']->pluck('created_at')->format('d-m-Y')

Answer (score 0):

In your table related model,

```
class ModelName{

        //add this line
        protected $dates = ['created_at','updated_at'];
}
```

Defining`$dates` in model will automatically give you the carbon instances of dates.

Comment: Please re-read the question, the cols are already Carbon instances.

Comment: There is no need to add `created_at` and `updated_at` to the `$dates` property as these are Carbon instances by default.